# Error when sending public access key for iOS application to GAE application

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, api-key, google-client

I have tried sending a public API access key for an iOS application from an iOS client to a Google App Engine (GAE) application.

The iOS client uses Google Cloud Endpoints (which in turn uses Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C) for contacting the server like this:

```
GTLServiceMyApp *service = [[GTLServiceMyApp alloc] init];
service.APIKey = ...

GTLQueryMyApp *query = [GTLQueryMyApp queryForAPITest];

[service executeQuery: query completionHandler: ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
}];
```

This works to some degree as expected. If the client sends an API key and none is defined it receives a specific error. If the client sends a correct API key (as defined for bundle identifier `com.mydomain.MyApp` in Google Developers Console) the call succeeds, but if the client sends a wrong or deleted API keys it again receives specific errors.

The odd thing is that employ this code on the server for  checking whether an API key is present (i.e. refer to it with `request.getParameter("key")`) the client receives an unexpected error:

```
@ApiMethod
public void test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String key = request.getParameter("key");
    ...
}
```

The error is as follows. It is unexpected because the passed API key contains a bundle identifier (not a per-IP or per-Referer restriction) namely the correct one (`com.mydomain.MyApp`).

> There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API
>   key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the
>   Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if
>   request from this IP or referer should be allowed.

Is this a feature or a bug? Can anybody tell what is going on here and how the GAE application may check whether a (valid) API key is present.

**UPDATE** If I modify the API key such that any application is allowed (i.e. with empty list of bundle identifiers) the client receives this error:

> Access Not Configured. The API (MyApp) is not enabled for your project.
>   Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.

Comment: Did you ever find out what happened, or how to solve it? I'm experiencing the same issue..

Comment: @Sti I had to resort to another workaround.